# Does Ubuntu 12.04 works for an Asus g75vw?

Tags: 12.04

I have an Asus g75vw, I tired to install ubuntu 12.04 but for some reason it damaged my windows installation and it never loaded me ubuntu to start installing it. I installed then an ubutntu 10.04 and I was able to install it but it does not support my hardware and i cant install my wifi drivers since I live in a hotel because of my job and they only have wireless connection, does ubuntu 12.04 really supports PC's with intel i7-3610QM CPU?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Compatibility with Asus g75vw, with intel i7-3610QM, with your wireless card, all of them, or something else entirely?

Comment: Well I am using ubuntu on an Asus laptop only & it runs as a charm. So problem must lie in somewhere you installation,plus I am damn sure that the laptop & CPU are supported by ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is a 99% chance your intel cpu is supported and you just botched the install. You can always test Ubuntu hardware compatibility by booting from a Live cd or Usb drive. Chances are if your hardware is new 10.04 is not the way to go, try booting from the 12.04 Ubuntu cd (Hopefully it is the live disk) or usb drive and see if your hardware functions normally (albiet slowly because it's running from optical).